# Snowflake Varchar Concatination

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having an issue with concatenation. Here is the problem-
When My Date is NULL I want NULL to be retuned but when the date is not Null I want the Values to be enclosed by '. Example '08/21/2021 11:20:23'.
The code below is not showing the addition of '. What am I missing here?

```js
var cmd = `       Select Case When max(DATE1) IS NULL then NULL else concat('''', Max(TO_VARCHAR(DATE1)),'''') end as Max_DT from  Table1
       where TABLE_NAME= ''${ITableName}'' ;`;
       
       
    // Run the statement.
    var sql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
    var result = sql.execute();
    result.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

> *When My Date is NULL I want NULL to be retuned but when the date is not Null I want the Values to be enclosed by '*

The CASE expression seems to be superfluous, as TO_VARCHAR() could handle it itself `TO_VARCHAR(MAX(DATE1), '''mm/dd/yyyy, hh24:mi:ss''')`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Table1(TABLE_NAME TEXT,DATE1 DATETIME)
AS
SELECT * FROM  (VALUES( 'a', CURRENT_DATE), ('b', NULL));

SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       TO_VARCHAR(MAX(DATE1), '''mm/dd/yyyy, hh24:mi:ss'''),
       TO_VARCHAR(MAX(DATE1), 'mm/dd/yyyy, hh24:mi:ss')
FROM Table1;
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I am using this script within JAVASCRIPT therefore I don't need , with Timestamp

Comment: How can I remove , from your result?